# ArgumentNullException was unhandled

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, dropbox-api

I am new to C# and Windows Phone 7 development and while trying to use the [Dropnet](http://dkdevelopment.net/what-im-doing/dropnet/) api, I am getting an error:

```
using DropNet;

namespace Hello
{

public partial class App : Application
{
    public PhoneApplicationFrame RootFrame { get; private set; }

    public static DropNetClient DropNetClient { get; set; }

    public App()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        InitializePhoneApplication();

        DropNetClient = new DropNetClient("api key", "secret");
//I've correct app key and secret inserted here

        DropNetClient.GetTokenAsync((userLogin) =>
        {
            //Dont really need to do anything with userLogin, 
//DropNet takes care of it for now
        },
    (error) =>
    {
        //Handle error
    });

        var url = DropNetClient.BuildAuthorizeUrl();
//getting error here


    }
}
```

The error I am getting is

`ArgumentNullException was unhandled

Value cannot be null

Parameter name: userLogin`

As per http://dkdevelopment.net/what-im-doing/dropnet/ the code should work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from the link you provided:

```
_client = new DropNetClient("API KEY", "API SECRET", "USER TOKEN", "USER SECRET");
// OR
_client = new DropNetClient("API KEY", "API SECRET");
_client.UserLogin = new UserLogin { Token = "USER TOKEN", Secret = "USER SECRET" };
```

You're missing the UserLogin initialization.

Comment: I think we use `user token` and `user secret` when logging in second time, after the user has logged in once (and application has stored the token and secret). For first time login the code in the question should be correct.
Just that coming from Java background, I'm having a bit tough time understanding what's going on here. :)

Comment: You're supposed to bring the user to the dropbox authentication page, where he can login and authorize your app. Then you retrieve the user token and user secret, and you can use them however you want. That's steps 2 and 2.5 on the website you linked.